# how to implement FTP using java?

Tags: java, ftp, client-server

I am working with FTP.......i have to embedd a msg to a image file at client side and i have to send it to the server....on the server side i have to retrieve the image file and then i will retrieve the message. I have completed the embedding the message and retrieve the message using cryptography and steganography techniques. I am loking for how can i transfer that file from client to server.....i have to work with FTP.....how can use FTP successfully to transfer a file from client to server and retrieve it on server side?

Comment: your question seems has way to much information not concerning the question:)

Comment: You can rely on combination of UNIX commands with Java, check if this helps :http://techforumnetwork.com/questions_answers/java-questions_answers/ftp-file-transfer-with-java-unix/

Answer (score 7):

You can use apache commons [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html). They have a good example on that page.

Answer (score 1):

To add to CoolBeans answer, there are a number of existing packages that handles ftp. Implementing it yourself is not a good idea. My personal favourite is [ftp4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/).