# How do you upload a file to an FTP server?

Tags: java, upload, ftp, download

I created a function to download files from an FTP server that I have access to.  How would I upload files back to the FTP server?

Below is the download_files method i used:

```
public static void download_files(String un, String pw, String ip, String dir, String fn, String fp){

    URLConnection con;
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;

    try{
        URL url = new URL("ftp://"+un+":"+pw+"@"+ip+"/"+dir+"/"+fn+";type=i");
        con = url.openConnection();
        in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        out = new FileOutputStream(fp+fn);

        int i = 0;
        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[1024];

        while ((i = in.read(bytesIn)) >= 0) {
            out.write(bytesIn, 0, i);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error while FTP'ing "+fn);
    }finally{
        try{
            out.close();
            in.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error while closing FTP connection");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to implement FTP using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720539/how-to-implement-ftp-using-java)

Comment: I have a doubt, is this above code(Download files from ftp) will work in android?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use the [FTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-1.4.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) Class from the [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library.

This is a snippet with an example:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
FileInputStream fis = null;

try {
    client.connect("ftp.domain.com");
    client.login("admin", "secret");

    //
    // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
    //
    String filename = "Touch.dat";
    fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

    //
    // Store file to server
    //
    client.storeFile(filename, fis);
    client.logout();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        client.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Snippet taken from http://www.kodejava.org/examples/356.html

Comment: For those having issues with saving data on server. Add client.enterLocalPassiveMode() before storing file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708147/ftpclient-storefile-uploads-slowly-and-then-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3):

I have used the EDT FTP package, a free GPL library for FTP in Java: http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpj/overview.html

Here is a code sample, from the Demo.java class they provide:

```
ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.setRemoteHost("hostname");

// connect
ftp.connect();

// login
ftp.login("user", "password");

// set up passive ASCII transfers
ftp.setConnectMode(FTPConnectMode.PASV);
ftp.setType(FTPTransferType.ASCII);

// get directory and print it to console            
String[] files = ftp.dir(".", true);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    log.debug(files[i]);

// copy file to server 
ftp.put("test.txt", "test.txt");

// copy file from server
ftp.get("test.txt" + ".copy", "test.txt");

// delete file from server
ftp.delete("test.txt");

// Shut down client                
ftp.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [FTP4J](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/) as well...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [apache-commons-net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) they have a some FTP tools which may help you out!