# How to store file as byte array using FTPClient?

Tags: java, file-upload, ftp-client

I'm working on FTP-Client tool for connection to ftp.

At this time, I need to upload to ftp via this tool. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527664/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-an-ftp-server) and first answer, it's possible to use `FileInputStream` for saving the files. But i want to store file as a byte array, not `FileInputStream`.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Use [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) to wrap the byte array which containes the data you want to upload, and then use this stream in place of the FileInputStream. E.g. something like:

```
byte[] mydata = <get your data>;
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(mydata);
ftpClient.storeFile("remoteName", stream);
stream.close(); // Not strictly needed for ByteArrayInputStream
```

Answer (score -2):

You can user ByteArrayOutputStream to store byte and can get the byte array.

```
 InputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 // write bytes here
 baos.write(bytes)

//to get bytes 

byte[] bArr = baos.toByteArray();
```