# executing multiple cmd commands to connect FTP using java?

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

Am trying to connect FTP connection via command prompt. For that I execute multiple command prompt commands in a single run using Java. I need to pull records using FTP. Here I show my command prompt commands Step by step.

**cmd commands:**

- cd Desktop
- FTP 128.100.100.1
- user id
- pswd
- QUOTE SITE FILETYPE=JES
- PUT test10.txt(filename)

These are the 6 commands I want to execute one by one in the same order, I tried but I cant achieve this, so I hope anyone can suggest some idea to run this code

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

Comment: FTP is it's own console program. It's not CMD. FTP has it's own script files. See `ftp /?`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt,Noodles no using cmd prompt only am connecting ftp.

Comment: @AndrewL but that is not clear for me can you please share any other link.

Comment: Just concat using ampersand

Comment: @AndrewL Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd Desktop && FTP 128.100.100.1 && user id && pswd && QUOTE SITE FILETYPE=JES && PUT test10.txt"); Is this correct or want to change syntax or anything

Comment: Do one ampersand and please try it yourself first, then debug. You don't have to ask, experiment before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you upload a file to an FTP server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527664/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-an-ftp-server)

Comment: @AndrewL yeah i tried it is showing error, but i couldn't find exactly what error.

Comment: Well, can't help you there my friend

Comment: @AndrewL okay no prob. Thank you. i'll figure it out.

Comment: Why don't you use a single batch file instead of running commands separately ?

Comment: @11thdimension i dont have any idea on that can you please share some examples

Comment: You puy all the commands except the first into a text file and `ftp -s script.txt`.