# best way to upload/download to a file server using spring?

Tags: spring, file-upload, upload, fileserver

I was reading spring [Uploading Files Getting Started Guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/).In this guide the file was saved in local file system using nio.

I wonder what should I do if I want to save files to a file server?I found sftp and nfs,is nfs better when the file server is in the same lan with the tomcat server?Is there any ohter ways?

Comment: There are many libraries which you can use . check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527664/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-an-ftp-server. Also check apache camel

Comment: @pvpkiran I checked out the question you suggested,all the answers were talking about FTP,so I guess your opinion is FTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 months with no answers, I guess there is no "standard" way to do it.But as the question that @pvpkiran recommended in the comments,I also guess that FTP or SFTP is a some sort of common way to do it.